# Pass a reference of a struct to an func not expecting a pointer

Tags: go, pointers, grpc

I was looking into grips with go and have a question regarding the helloworld grpc demo in go. Link to repo [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/examples/features/multiplex/server/main.go)

The server implementation calls one of the grpc autogenerated function to start the server and listen for incoming messages. However, the code passes a reference " &hwServer{}" of the struct to the function as below.

```
// Register Greeter on the server.
hwpb.RegisterGreeterServer(s, &hwServer{})
```

Meanwhile the autogenerated Function has the following signature, which at that position expects an interface but not as a pointer:

```
func RegisterGreeterServer(s grpc.ServiceRegistrar, srv GreeterServer) {
s.RegisterService(&Greeter_ServiceDesc, srv)
```

}

Therefore my question is, can I use both, a reference and pass by value as long as it satisfies the interface requirement? Otherwise I was used, that is the func arg expected a value, I cannot pass a pointer.

Comment: 1. A pointer is not a reference! 2. Any value that implements an interface can be assigned to an interface variable, here `srv GreeterServer`. 3. A pointer to the type of hwServer (which you didn't show but is the relevant thing to look at) implements GreeterService. 4. _Please_ take the Tour of Go to learn about interfaces and what types implement which interface. 5. You never need a pointer to an interface value. 6. The call works by simply assigning a value to a variable. Assignability of values to interface variables requires the "implements"-relation you will have to learn.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying this. I have a little follow up question: The hwServer explicitly implements the SayHello (which is necessary for the interface) but not the mustEmbedUnimplementedGreeterServer(). Is it sufficient, that the embedded UnimplementedGreeterServer implements mustEmbedUnimplementedGreeterServer? Thanks.

Comment: As already mentioned: I do not know the type of hwServer (you didn't include that) and have no time digging through the rather large example.

Comment: "Is it sufficient.." - yes. [Method sets](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_sets) are the relevant concept here [and](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Struct_types) "If S contains an embedded field T, the method sets of S and *S both include promoted methods with receiver T". Note that `UnimplementedGreeterServer` provides default implementations ([e.g.](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/examples/helloworld/helloworld/helloworld_grpc.pb.go#L73)) for your gRPC functions so your go code will compile without alteration after a method is added to the gRPC proto file.

Comment: Thank you @Brits that explained it really well and also the links were super helpful.